# ical (RFC5545) sequence property

Tags: icalendar, rfc5545

I'm implementing RFC5545 and I'm just not understanding the SEQUENCE property and when it changes.  I've played with events in Apple's Calendar app numerous times and keep exporting the .ics and nothing I do ever seems to change that sequence number.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The SEQUENCE property comes into play only when scheduling is involved.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546#section-2.1.4

Comment: actually not just scheduling - also indicates which version of an event instance is the latest

Comment: The SEQUENCE property automatically change the sequence no. when there is a change in scheduling or we need to manually (through script) update the sequence number each time?